# Ionic android image path from gallery

Tags: android, image, path, gallery, ionic-framework

I am new in Ionic, I'm trying to get the proper image path using camera plugin. I have also attached the image.
Please let me know how I can get the image from the following path on my device[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
.config( function( $compileProvider )
  { 
  $compileProvider.imgSrcSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|file|content|local|blob|cdvfile):|data:image\//);
  }
)
```

add your project